# GIT: How do I remove any configs that makes a remote branch track a local branch?

Tags: git, github

What the title says. Version of git is 1.5.6.3
I've tried using git branch --track
But it throws errors saying that the branches already exist. I am confused.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a branch named, e.g., "develop" and you want to "unlink" it from a similarly named branch on a remote, try this:

```
git config --remove-section branch.develop
```

This will remove the configuration from your local working copy.

Take a look at `git config --list` before and after this change to see the difference.  You could obviously accomplish the same thing by simply editing your `.git/config` file, but I like to use `git config` instead.